# Is there a better way to organize class objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have a bunch of ‘item’ objects and I want to organize them in the most functional way possible. I’ve checking the python formatting guide and didn’t find much information. Currently I’m doing the following:

```
class Items(object):
    
    def __init__(self, name, a, b)
        self.name = name
        etc.


def mod_b(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        i = items_dict[item]
        i.b = False


items_dict = {
    ‘Shirt’: Items(‘shirt’, 1, True)
    ‘Ball’ : Items(‘ball’, 2, False)
    ***etc. for 100 items ***
    }

#get a list of items with variable self.b=True

My_list = i for i in items_dict if items_dict[i].b

mod_b(my_list)
```

As you can see, I’m retrieving a list of keys that match what I need from the dictionary. Then later I use the keys to change variables in each Item.

The other options I know of include:

1. Creating a variable for each object then putting those objects in a .set()
2. Saving the actual objects to the list I retrieve rather than just the key.

I’m just wondering what others do, or what is viewed as best practice when working with large numbers of objects, before I get too deep into the project.

Comment: There is no one "best" way of representing data in your code, not without knowing what you aim to do with the data later. Loading the records into a dataframe may be best for some use cases, where a list of dictionaries may be best in others. A "`set()`" is unlikely to be the best solution here, unless you require uniqueness somehow (and even then, it won't just work with this kind of data type). You should describe what the purpose of your program is, and how the data will be accessed, and/or modified, and indicate why you feel the representation you've chosen doesn't work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comments yet so this is a pseudo answer. Follow PEP8 first of all, for style/format. Otherwise parse established python projects on GitHub for practices. Use useful variable_names not `b`. Put globals in CAPS at the top of the module. Call your dict with `.get` to pass a default value. Your iterator statement belongs within `[]`s can could be defined as a method of the class Items to return an iterator instead of a list. Generators/Iterators can be better than lists especially when they get lengthy and code-ey. <- that may answer your question: if you have large data sets that maybe are stored in a database file, you don't want to read them into a list but rather write generators to `yield`. This will get tricky though if you're also manipulating the data since it won't be living in memory in a mutable list, so you may be appending to a file. Dicts `key,value` pairs can be iterated over via a dict's `.items`, btw. `mod_b` could also be an `@classmethod` decorator on a Items class method, maybe. There's many ways to do whatever you want to do in Python so like the commenter pointed out, depends.